# If $f_n(x) \to f(x)$ in the Schwartz space, $f_n(Ax) \to f(Ax)$ for any invertible matrix $A$?

Tags: convergence-divergence, change-of-variable, schwartz-space

Let $f_n$ be a sequence of Schwartz functions on $\mathbb{R}^N$ converging to another Schwartz function in the Schwartz space $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^N)$.

Now, let $A : \mathbb{R}^N \to \mathbb{R}^N$ be any invertible matrix. Then, functions $f_{A,n}$ and $f_A$ defined by
\begin{equation}
f_{A,n}(x):= f_n(Ax) \qquad f_A(x):=f(Ax)
\end{equation}
are again Schwartz functions on $\mathbb{R}^N$.

Now, my question is

> Is it true that $f_{A,n} \to f_A$ in $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^N)$?

I think this is very plausible, but cannot justify rigorously. Could anyone please help me?

Add 1. Let $lVert f \rVert_{\alpha, \beta}:= \sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}^N} \lvert x^{\alpha} (D^{\beta} f)(x) \rvert$ for any multi-indices $\alpha$ and $\beta$. Then, $f_n \to f$ in the Scwhartz space means that $\lVert f_n-f \rVert_{\alpha, \beta} \to 0$ for all $\alpha, \beta$.

Add 2. I am aware that $\widehat{f_A}(\xi) = \frac{1}{\lvert \det A \rvert} \widehat{f}(A^{-T} \xi)$ where $\widehat{f}$ means the Fourier transform. Also, I know that the Fourier transform is a continuous linear bijection on the Scwhartz space whose inverse is also continuous. However, this does not seem to resolve my main issue because $A^{-T}$ persists in $\widehat{f}$.

Add 3. Let $A= (A^i_j)$ and $(Ax)_j=A^{i}_j x_i$ in the components w.r.t the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^N$, where $i,j=1, \cdots, N$ and I have used the summation convention. Then any partial derivative $(D^{\alpha} f_{A}(x)$ is written as a sum of homogeneous polynomials in $A^i_j$ of order $\lvert \alpha \rvert$. I am stuck at how to use invertibility of $A$ to show that $\lVert f_{A,n}-f_A \rVert_{\alpha, \beta} \to 0$ if $\lVert f_n-f \rVert_{\alpha, \beta} \to 0$. I also guess there must be some more elegant way to prove this and the Fourier transform looked like a good candidate. But, as in the previous item, I still run into the problem of dealing with $A^{-T}\xi$.

Comment: What did you try? And what does convergence mean in this context?  Start there.

Comment: if $A$ is invertible, then it's a bijection on $\mathbb{R}^N.$  Also, it helps to specify what convergence you are using here.

Comment: @peek-a-boo I wrote $Ax$ in components and tried to compute, but I do not see where invertibility iss used. Also, I believe that "convergence in the Schwartz space" is a well-known concept.

Comment: @dezdichado Ok, I will specify the seminorms and all. Please wait a bit.

Comment: I know what convergence in Schwartz space means here. I want you to say it, and to apply it to this sequence of composite functions, and point out exactly where you’re stuck. If it helps work things out in 1D first, or for small sizes of multiindices.

Comment: @Keith my point about the bijection is that if this is really a "Fourier analysis/Schwartz space" problem.

Comment: @dezdichado I added the details and where I am stuck.

Comment: @peek-a-boo I have described where I am stuck at. For $N >1$ my failure in using invertibility of $A$ does not seem to diminish for lower dimensions.

Comment: When you calculate $(\partial^{\alpha}f_A)(x)$, you get something like $P_{\alpha}(A)\cdot (\partial^{\alpha}f)(Ax)$, i.e some junk involving $A$ alone times derivatives of $f$ evaluated at the point $Ax$, not $x$. This difference in evaluation point is crucial to notice. So, to check convergence in Schwartz space we need to multiply $\partial^{\alpha}(f_{n,A})(x)$ by an $x^{\beta}$ term, and check the result converges to $0$. But now you see we need to write the $x^{\beta}$ in terms of $(Ax)^{\beta}$, because we need to force the argument $Ax$ to appear to invoke Schwartzness.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Ohh...$x =A^{-1}(Ax)$ is where you use the invertibility assumption!! Thank you very much for your insight.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Wait, I see that you just edited your answer? I will try myself with $x=A^{-1}(Ax)$ anyway.

Comment: yes correct, write $x=A^{-1}(Ax)$ to then express $x^{\beta}$ in terms of $(Ax)^{\beta}$ times some junk involving $A^{-1}$ alone. Then, take supremum over all $x$ (this will be finite since we have $J_{\alpha,\beta}(A)\cdot (Ax)^{\beta}\cdot (\partial^{\alpha} f_n)(Ax)$, where $J_{\alpha,\beta}(A)$ is some junk involving $A$ (or $A^{-1}$) alone… so this is some $A$-junk times a Schwartz seminorm of $f_n$).